How to get a parameter from specific function type signature
I think it's best to explain with an example: I'm working with winston and are facing this type:
interface LeveledLogMethod {
  (message: string, callback: LogCallback): Logger;
  (message: string, meta: any, callback: LogCallback): Logger;
  (message: string, ...meta: any[]): Logger;
  (message: any): Logger;
  (infoObject: object): Logger;
}

Now, I want to get the type of meta in (message: string, ...meta: any[]): Logger.
The only thing I could come up with is Parameters<LeveledLogMethod>, which gives me the type [infoObject: object] (i.e. the parameters of the last signature declared there).
Is there a way to get the parameters of (message: string, ...meta: any[]): Logger instead?

This is a limitation of overloads and one reason to avoid them. You can write helper types which sort of kind of do what you want but they don't scale well. See linked q/a for more info (OverloadedParameters but you'd need to extend that definition to handle more call signatures)

@jcalz I see. Thank you for your reply!
